# How to get the same time the update(currentTime:) function uses? (before it is called)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

Question: The `update(currentTime:)` function in `SKScene` is called every frame with a `currentTime` argument. I'm wondering how to get the time from the same source `update(currentTime:)` uses without using the `update` function. I only found `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` which is different.

Reason: To calculate `timeSinceLastUpdate` you need an instance variable called `timeOfLastUpdate`. To implement `timeOfLastUpdate` you need to set it to an arbitrary value before the first update which makes the first calculation of `timeSinceLastUpdate` incorrect. You could have a simple if statement to detect this or use optionals but that is an unneeded branch which could be avoided if I just set `timeOfLastUpdate` in `didMoveToView(view:)`. And that is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I have noticed that `currentTime` returns the time in seconds the device has been running, meaning it is reset every time you reboot.  There are ways to get this value, but for what you are doing, rickster's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

The first `timeSinceLastUpdate` will always be different from the rest. Typically one stores the absolute time from the previous `update` call and subtracts it from the current call's time to get a `timeSinceLastUpdate`.  If the previous time doesn't exist because you're on the first pass through the render loop — it's set to zero or infinity or negative something or whatever sentinel value you initialized it to, just set your `timeSinceLastUpdate` to some nominal value for getting started.  Something like your frame interval (16.67 ms if you're going for 60 fps) would make sense — you don't want game code that depends on that time interval to do something wild because you passed it zero or some wildly huge value.

In fact, it's not a bad idea to have logic for normalizing your `timeSinceLastUpdate` to something sane in the event that it gets foo large — say, because your user paused and resumed the game. If you have game entities (such as GameplayKit agents) whose movement follows some sort of `position += velocity * timeSinceLastUpdate` model, you want them to move by one frame's worth of time when you resume from a pause, not take a five-minute pause times velocity and jump to hyperspace.

If you initialize your previous time to zero, subtract, and normalize to your expected frame interval, you'll cover both the starting and unpausing cases with the same code.

Comment: I'm wondering how to get the "previous" time from the `didMoveToView` method. Since the current solution requires evaluating a boolean expression ~60 times per second even though it is only needed once at the first update.

Comment: As I noted, that Boolean check is useful/needed for more than just the first update. And it's thousands of times faster than everything else you might be doing in your update method — what I'm getting at is that trying to invent a fictitious "previous" time just to optimize that check away is overthinking things.

Answer (score 3):

You could always use coalesce:

```
let deltaTime = currentTime - (previousTime ?? currentTime).
```

On first loop,  your deltaTime is 0 (Should be this)  after that,  it is the change

Of course previousTime must be an optional for this to work